# Java: Alternative to using .clone() when modifying an argument?

Tags: java, clone

So I've always been told that it's bad practice to modify arguments to methods (at least when it's not intuitive). Normally I'd use something simple, like:

```
  public Type method(Type Object) {
    Type otherObject = Object.clone();
            // do stuff to otherObject

    return otherObject;
}
```

This is something I do quite frequently, albiet sparingly. Is there a nicer way to do this? 
For example, A way to make java pass by value, instead of by reference, so that modifying the argument wouldn't have unforseen consiquences for users of my classes. 
Besides being less clear(sort of) clone methods presumably run in O(n) time, so not having to do this would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: `clone methods presumably run in O(n) time` - doesn't make any sense at all (for one: which n?). Also, you pass absolutely everything in java by value, for objects you just pass the pointer to it and no you can't change that. But then: There's no inherent difference in performance between a copy constructor (which c++ does in the background) and a clone method (a virtual method has some advantages though) - but nothing stops you from using a copy constructor in java as well.

Comment: The irony in the phrase "something I do quite frequently, albeit sparingly," made me giggle.  I had to do something similar when creating a dirty implementation of a memory cache.  When people would get the object, if I didn't return a copy, different portions of the code would modify it at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security point of view (and that usually keeps us honest), `clone` is usually the wrong thing to do (except `HttpCookie` - it's mutable but `final`). If the object has a dodgy implementation, you'll be copying that as well.

The best thing you can do is make, `Type` immutable. The problem goes away. No need to copy.

If it is a mutable value, just construct a copy - `new Type(object)` or whatever. Remember to the copying should be done before checking that the contents of the object are valid, to avoid time-of-check to time-of-use bugs (TOCTOU/TOC2TOU).

Comment: I don't really see "we copy the actual object and not create a completely different one" as a disadvantage. I assume this can be important in situations where we enable users to load arbitrary classes, but I think most of the time we actually want to copy the actual object. Slicing behavior from c++ isn't wanted most of the time either.

Answer (score 0):

If one has variables `X` and `Y` of type `SomeClass` which happens to include a copy constructor, and one says `X = new SomeClass(Y);` when Y is non-null, then `X` will receive a new instance which will be of type `SomeClass`, regardless of the actual type of `Y`.  By contrast, if one instead uses `X = (SomeClass)Y.clone()`, *and the actual type of Y implements `clone` correctly*, one will receive an object of the same type as `Y`.  Which approach is "better" will depend upon how the program is supposed to behave with derived types.